# Surround characters with HTML tag

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace a text in javascript. For example the text is:
< + class abc > -

I want the result:

```
<span class="operators"> < </span><span class="operators"> + </span>
<span class="keywords">class</span> abc <span class="operators"> > </span>
<span class="operators"> - </span>
```

Bud the second replace rule does also replace the < and >, and the class attribute in the HTML tags.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: so, what´s your code so far?

Comment: A proper approach would be to build a tokenizer which splits the input string into tokens and then wraps each token in a corresponding tag (DOM element). I.e. process each part individually. You might want to look at how http://codemirror.net/ is doing this.

Comment: I want the result, but I am too lazy to try anything, please do it for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very basic example:

```
var operators = ["<", "+", "-", ">"],
    keywords  = ["class"];

"< + class abc > -".replace(/[^ ]+/g, function(m) {
    if (operators.indexOf(m) > -1)
        return '<span class="operators">' + m + '</span>';
    else if (keywords.indexOf(m) > -1)
        return '<span class="keywords">' + m + '</span>';
    return m;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6Np26/

Comment: Bud in IE8 or earlier is the indexOf method not supported. How bad.

Comment: @user2190492 Or you could simply use a shim from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var x = '< + class abc > -';
var array = x.split(/\s/);

var ops = /^[<>+-\/]$/;
var keywords = /^(class)$/

var result  = [];
for(var i = 0; i <  array.length; i++){
    var item =  array[i];
    if(ops.test(item)) {
        result.push('<span class="operators"> ' + item + ' </span>')
    } else if(keywords.test(item)){
        result.push('<span class="keywords"> ' + item + ' </span>')
    } else {
        result.push(item)
    }
}

console.log(result.join(' '))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CUXPH/1/)